# how to find the line integral of a square with vertices $(-1,0) (0,1) (1,0) $ and $ (0,-1)$ when $F=xyi+xy^2j$

Tags: vector-analysis

I know how to usually do these kinds of questions but usually there is something given to substitute for x or y in F or parametric equation is given.

Comment: "j"? Do you mean by that $i$?

Comment: i and j are unit vectors i cap and j cap

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Green's Theorem, then you need to concoct your own parametrization.  In this case, the curve is made of 4 pieces, so the integral breaks into 4 parts.  The segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ is given by $x=t-1$, $y=t$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$.  Work out that integral and then do the other 3 segments similarly.  Then add up the 4 results.

The point of such exercises is to make you appreciate Green's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

One way: if $S$ is the given square and $\partial S$ its boundary,
$$\int_{\partial S}xydx+xy^2dy\underbrace{=}_{\text{Green's Theorem}}\iint_{S}(y^2-x)dxdy=\ldots$$

Comment: Thankyou .... But I need to do it normally... I want to know my mistake

Comment: Well, in that case, write your work.

Comment: Iam sorry but that's too jumbled... I can try to explain you see I divided the square into 4 curves then iam solving each curve separately but iam not able to convert all the equation into x so I can take the limits of x only that's where iam stuck

Comment: Look at the excellent  B. Goddard's answer (+1)